# Split Variable by Text In Between Numbers In Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
1 a more or less orderly pile or heap:                 a precariously       balanced stack of books; a neat stack of papers.

2 a large, usually conical, circular, or rectangular pile of hay, straw, or the like.

3 Often, stacks. a set of shelves for books or other materials ranged     compactly one above the other, as in a library.
```

It's **messy** to say the least. I want to grab the text between each number and store it to a variable. Between numbers 1 and 2 i would have *var1*, and between 2 and 3 have *var2* store the text. Here's where it gets tricky, Sometimes the numbers go up to 24, sometimes they only go to 1. I am quite inexperienced with parsing in python and I have no idea what to write to make this work. How would I parse this data? TIA

Comment: what about blank lines?

Comment: Does it need to be a separate variable for each or could you just store them in a list?

Comment: Blank Lines i can get rid of, those dont matter.

Comment: Are you okay using a regex? Is there a newline at the end of each one?

Comment: @PerlPingu Sure! it can be a list or separate variables, it does not matter

Comment: @DaLord Sure! The newline does not appear all of the time, which is why splitting by the numbers would probably be the safest way.

Comment: In essence you want to discard the line numbers and put the contents of each line into a separate string? Do you want to remove excess blanks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the input file so that there would be no line-break between the second and third non-empty lines. (You said newlines would not always appear.)

```
1 a more or less orderly pile or heap:                 a precariously       balanced stack of books; a neat stack of papers.

2 a large, usually conical, circular, or rectangular pile of hay, straw, or the like.3 Often, stacks. a set of shelves for books or other materials ranged     compactly one above the other, as in a library.
```

This code may do what you want.

- `if line` serves to avoid processing blank lines.
- `re.split` splits the lines at numbers followed by white space.
- `split_lines.split()` splits lines at whitespace so that they can be joined back together by the next line, to have less whitespace.
- If the resulting line is non-empty it's appended to the list of results.

---

```
import re

result = []
with open('jake.txt') as jake:
    for line in jake:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            for split_lines in re.split(r'[0-9]+\s+', line):
                items = split_lines.split()
                new_line = ' '.join(items).strip()
                if new_line:
                    result.append(new_line)
for r in result:
    print (r)
```

Here is the output.

```
a more or less orderly pile or heap: a precariously balanced stack of books; a neat stack of papers.
a large, usually conical, circular, or rectangular pile of hay, straw, or the like.
Often, stacks. a set of shelves for books or other materials ranged compactly one above the other, as in a library.
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, lets give this a try. We are going to use a regex to match on the first of the line which is a digit. Then we will take everything after that. We will store that in `var` so that we can iterate over the group and pull it out

```
import re

regex = r"^\d+\s+(?P<var>.*)"

test_str = """1 a more or less orderly pile or heap:                 a precariously       balanced stack of books; a neat stack of papers.
2 a large, usually conical, circular, or rectangular pile of hay, straw, or the like.
3 Often, stacks. a set of shelves for books or other materials ranged     compactly"""

# Use the iterator to move across each row/match
matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE) # use MUTLINE so that we can process each row.

for match in matches:
   print(match.groupdict()['var']) # pull out the var we are looking for
   print('----')
```

Here is the output:

```
a more or less orderly pile or heap: a precariously       balanced stack of books; a neat stack of papers.
----
a large, usually conical, circular, or rectangular pile of hay, straw, or the like.
----
Often, stacks. a set of shelves for books or other materials range compactly
----
```

Will this get you close?